# button react js doesn't work but it is the good code

Tags: reactjs, database, button, crud

I'm following this video to make a crud in React Js.The problem is at 13 minutes.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-quobUzNmuA

I copy his code but it doesn't work. I don't understand why.

My screenshots here :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp1xh.png)
[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHeR7.png)

Thank you all

Comment: It is more appropriate to populate your question with real code and _not_ links to some youtube video and code-screenshots. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did a typo on line no 45 in your code. as I can see  the ref should be chnage to txtAge instead of txtName.

update it in your code. that may help you.

so it should be :

```
<input type="text" ref="txtAge" placeholder="Enter Age" />
```

Comment: Do you know a good extension to show reactjs please ?

Comment: what do you actully mean by extension

Comment: For php I use intelliphense plug in/extension for visual Studio code for example